# Manga where the main character is tricked by a goddess and given the 'curse of the hero'

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for an isekai manga. In it, the main character and his class are summoned by a goddess, but they decide to send someone back to tell their families. The protagonist “goes back” but it was a trick by the goddess and the mc was dropped in a forest full of monsters and given the curse of the hero (he can only talk to species considered enemies of humans).

In the forest he runs into an abandoned god/goddess, and he explains to the god/goddess what a loner is, so the “Loner god” gives him the blessing of the loner which makes him immortal, but he can’t level up because of the regeneration.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is "*Is This Hero For Real?*"

> Kang Hansoo was summoned to this world with his classmates.
>
> His classmates were amazed by this brand new world and the magic in
> it, but the only thing Hansoo wanted to do was quickly return home.
> “Why would I give up my warm, comfortable house to have an adventure
> in this world…?
> Even the goddess that summoned me said that if I wasn’t willing to,
> there was nothing she could do to force me and promised to return me
> to my original world.
> She did teleport me, but…
> When I opened my eyes, I was still in this world!
> All of my friends were gone, and the only thing around me was
> monsters!!
> A goddess tricked me…?
> How do I get back home now…?
> More than that, how do I survive here…?!“
>
> [image]

His 'blessing' is actually a curse

> [image]

Later in the series he meets a "loner god"

> [image]