# Manga where the main character was cursed with only understanding hostile creases and massively decreased exp

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The manga starts with a whole school class being reincarnated and a goddess shows up in front of the heroes explaining everything until the main character said he didn't wanna do it and wanted to go home.  She opened up a portal and he got sent to a forest where he found out he was cursed with only understanding hostile creases and massively decreased exp.

Comment: Probably a dupe of this question: [Manga where the main character is tricked by a goddess and given the 'curse of the hero'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/266124/20774)

Comment: Ah, "creases" is probably "creatures" as per your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[Is This Hero for Real?](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/is-this-hero-for-real)***...?

> **When a goddess transports Hansoo Kang and his classmates to a magical fantasy world to become heroes, it’s like a dream come true. But when Hansoo declines to risk his life for a world that isn’t his own, the goddess leaves him for dead, alone in the forest.** That’s when he realizes she’s not what she seems. With the help of a loner god, Hansoo faces the hostile new world and earns powerful blessings to help him survive. But his goal isn’t to save the world; it’s to return home… well, after he gets revenge on the goddess that is.
>
> [image: Promotional art for "Is This Hero for Real?"]

The Korean protagonist, Hansoo Kang, and his classmates are transported to the fantasy world of Fantasia by a goddess and told that they'll all become heroes and be blessed with powers to enable them to defeat the Demon King threatening this world. Hansoo Kang's classmates are apparently fine with this, but he asks the goddess to send him home, as he doesn't believe that someone who worries about his family can save the world.

She opens a portal for him, but when he steps through it, he finds himself in a forest surrounded by vicious beastmen, instead of being back on Earth. After being pursued by these beastmen for a while, he manages to open up a status screen, which reveals that he's a '[Curse] Hero' with a skill that automatically translates the languages of hostile races for him, but who'll receive a greatly decreased amount of experience from hunting and quests.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/is-this-hero-for-real/info).