# Manga about a summoned hero who gets tricked then saved by a different hero

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Looking for the name of a manga where the main character is summoned by a goddess. He and his class were summoned, but he wanted to go home, but instead of taking him home, they dropped him in the forest where another goddess found him and are now known ask the outcast. He becomes overpowered and fights off all of one specific monster, then goes to another one, and no one knows he is still in the same world and alive.

I think it was in color, but I don’t know too much; I just know this.

Comment: Hi. I had some difficulty interpreting the following sentence: _"they dropped him in the forest where another goddess found him and are now known ask the outcast"_ Did you mean that the main character is known as the outcast?

Comment: Likely a dupe of [Manga where the main character is tricked by a goddess and given the 'curse of the hero'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/266124/20774)

Answer (score 4):

This is *[Is This Hero For Real?](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/is-this-hero-for-real)*

> Kang Hansoo was summoned to this world with his classmates.
>
> His classmates were amazed by this brand new world and the magic in
> it, but the only thing Hansoo wanted to do was quickly return home.
> “Why would I give up my warm, comfortable house to have an adventure
> in this world…?
> Even the goddess that summoned me said that if I wasn’t willing to,
> there was nothing she could do to force me and promised to return me
> to my original world.
> She did teleport me, but…
> When I opened my eyes, I was still in this world!
> All of my friends were gone, and the only thing around me was
> monsters!!
> A goddess tricked me…?
> How do I get back home now…?
> More than that, how do I survive here…?!“
>
> [image]

Later in the series he meets an outcast "loner god"

> [image]

Comment: Definitely this one.  Hansoo starts off killing gnolls in the forest he lands in, trying to gain enough XP to level up.  After he wipes out all the gnolls, he move on and wipes out all the orcs, ultimately killing 300 000(!) of them in their hidden city.  He gets really, really (really) good at fighting, but between the [Hero] curse and the [Outsider] blessing he's permanently stuck at level 1.

Comment: Yes this is it thank you